# jQuery mouseup not being detected correctly

Tags: jquery, events, mousedown, event-propagation, mouseup

I have a div that contains a span. I have a mouseup, and mousedown event that should fire when pressing in the div. However it doesn't work correctly.

Please go to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ym7rM/

If you select the text and then try to drag it, it just detects the mousedown event,but not the mouseup.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Chrome.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I simplified the question, see the new fiddle.

Comment: Why would the mouseup event fire if the mouse isn't over the element with the mouse event attached to it?

Comment: If that is so, then why is the mousedown firing?

Comment: Why is the mousedown firing when?

Comment: @micha - would that be 'binded' our 'bound'   , sounds kind of awkward

Comment: The mouseup event also isn't firing when the mouseup happens inside the div (asexpected), as Alvaro pointed out. But yes, it would not fire outside the div either.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. Mouseup is not firing inside the orange div (where it should) .

Comment: micha, it isn't for me (under Firefox 15 on Windows 7, if that helps narrow things down), and apparently not for Alvaro under the version of Chrome he's using. So there is something unexpected happening here.

Comment: What browser? I have the problem in Chrome

Comment: See the new fiddle in the question please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mouseup event is being detected correctly; it's just that the browser is not firing a mouseup event after you perform a drag. This is an intentional behavior by the browser. You should also listen for the dragend event if you want to include the behavior that you are intending now.

Comment: With dragend instead of mouseup works correctly, what is the difference?

Comment: When you are dragging something, some of the mouse events are replaced by drag events. That is, `mousemove` becomes `drag` and `mouseup` becomes `dragend`. You'll find that the JavaScript event objects passed into handlers from drag events are different from mouse events in that the drag events contain a new object called `dataTransfer`.

Comment: Thanks for both, for the solution and the explanation.I will have to look deeper the drag events.

Answer (score -1):

the mouseup event is fired only inside the orange div. thats what you coded. try this http://jsfiddle.net/ur8J9/5/

Comment: Thanks.Please see the edited question. Your fiddle shows exactly my problem: only mousedown is fired, not mouseup.