# On Chrome and Opera, mousedown action on a selector control causes mousedown and mouseup events to fire

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, events, mouse

I’m developing  a javascript-based web app that displays various times series of weather data on a tab. Which time series is displayed on the tab is controlled by a select control with id = tempVarSelect. Changes to the tempVarSelect control are meant to execute  changeTempDisplay(), which hides and shows  time series graph on the tab. The changeTempDisplay() function is bound to changes in tempVarSelect via the Jquery mouseup event:

```
  $("#tempVarSelect").mouseup(function( ){ changeTempDisplay();      }); 

   function changeTempDisplay(){
     var tempVar = Number(document.getElementById("tempVarSelect").value); 
     switch (tempVar)
     {
      case 0:
        console.log(" temp_Display = " + tempVar);
        $("#tmaxGraph").show();
        $("#tmaxLabels").show();
        $("#tminGraph").hide();
        $("#tminLabels").hide(); 
        plotTMAX();
       break;
      case 1:
        console.log(" temp_Display = " + tempVar);
        $("#tmaxGraph").hide();
        $("#tmaxLabels").hide();
        $("#tminGraph").show();
        $("#tminLabels").show(); 
        plotTMIN();
       break;
      }  
   }
```

This works with Safari and Firefox, i.e. a mousedown-mousemove-mouseup sequence on the tempVarSelect selector causes the graph type selected on mouseup to display properly.

But on Chrome and Opera changeTempDisplay appears to fire on mousedown, causing the current time series display to be re-plotted and the tempVar number selected on mousedown to  be echoed to console.log. As a result, there is no change to the display. Mousemove and mouseup  causes the tempVarSelect selector to assign the correct tempVar value and highlight the correct selected variable on mouseup,  but because changeTempDisplay fires on mousedown, there is no change to the time series display. When I mousedown  on tempVarSelect after that, changeTempDisplay fires with the changed value of tempVar, and the display changes to the new time series as it should.

By conducting a  simplified test that echoes  mousedown and mouseup times to console.log, i.e.

var time0 = new Date().getTime();

```
  $("#tempVarSelect").bind("mouseup",function( ){
    time = new Date().getTime() - time0;
    console.log(" tempVarSelect mouseup at t = " + time);    
    });

  $("#tempVarSelect").bind("mousedown",function( ){
    time = new Date().getTime() - time0;
    console.log(" tempVarSelect mousedown at t = " + time);    
    });
```

I’ve found that what is actually happening is that a mousedown action triggers a mousedown-mouseup sequence in Chrome, but only mousedown in Safari and Firefox. As a result, changeTempDisplay() fires on a mousedown action in Chrome.

I’ve checked out similar problems (e.g., [jQuery mouseup not being detected correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231147/jquery-mouseup-not-being-detected-correctly)  ), but they don’t seem to apply to what I’m seeing.

Does anyone have any idea why this would occur?

Comment: I have found a work-around to this by deleting the Jquery binding and adding "onchange = "changeTempDisplay()" to the selector markup. I also tried "onclick = "changeTempDisplay()" but that produced the same problem in Chrome described above.