# Can I control a js google map's panning by dragging another element?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have two divs, one on top of the other. The bottom one contains the JS google map. The top one contains text and has a transparent background. Is there any way to control the panning of the map by dragging the top element?

Answer (score 1):

You could use some javascript with the Google Maps Api commands, in this case I believe you would need to use map.panBy(). You could assign this command to a drag action on the div using something like this:

```
var isDragging = false;
$("a")
.mousedown(function() {
    $(window).mousemove(function() {
        isDragging = true;
        $(window).unbind("mousemove");
    });
})
.mouseup(function() {
    var wasDragging = isDragging;
    isDragging = false;
    $(window).unbind("mousemove");
    if (!wasDragging) { //was clicking
        $("#throbble").show();
    }
});
```

Sources:

[Can you detect "dragging" in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127118/can-you-detect-dragging-in-jquery)

http://www.daveoncode.com/2008/11/17/playing-with-google-maps-api-part-two-create-custom-controls/