# replace mousemove by mousedrag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, drag

The title explains it all.I am facing problem when it comes to providing drag event. I tried replacing `mousemove` by `mousedown`, may be `mousedown` fires once and settles down, but it dint help. How can I programmatically do this.

In case you want to refer what code I am trying to manipulate you can refer this code; else ignore it:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".toolImage").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).parent(".toolTip").find(".toolTipDesc").css("display", "block");
    });
    $(".toolImage").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).parent(".toolTip").find(".toolTipDesc").css("display", "none");
    });
    var native_width = 0;
    var native_height = 0;

    //Now the mousemove function
    $(".magnify").mousemove(function (e) {

        if (!native_width && !native_height) {
            //This will create a new image object with the same image as that in .small
            //We cannot directly get the dimensions from .small because of the
            //width specified to 200px in the html. To get the actual dimensions we have
            //created this image object.
            var image_object = new Image();
            image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");

            native_width = image_object.width;
            native_height = image_object.height;
        } else {

            var magnify_offset = $(this).offset();
            var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
            var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;

            //Finally the code to fade out the glass if the mouse is outside the container
            if (mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0) {
                $(".large").fadeIn(100);
            } else {
                $(".large").fadeOut(100);
            }
            if ($(".large").is(":visible")) {
                var rx = Math.round(mx / $(".small").width() * native_width - $(".large").width() / 2) * -1;
                var ry = Math.round(my / $(".small").height() * native_height - $(".large").height() / 2) * -1;
                var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";

                //Time to move the magnifying glass with the mouse
                var px = (mx - $(".large").width() / 2);
                var py = (my - $(".large").height() / 2);

                $(".large").css({
                    left: px,
                    top: py + 10,
                    backgroundPosition: bgp
                });
            }
        }
    })

    $('.t1').mouseenter(function () {

        $('.pointerTxt').fadeIn();
    });

    $('.t1').mouseleave(function () {

        $('.pointerTxt').fadeOut();
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to focus more on defining what you want to achieve, because I  have absolutely no idea what to help you with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do everything in your `mousemove()` only when a mouse button is being pressed, right?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lbDown = false;

    $(".magnify").mousedown(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 1) {
            lbDown = true;
        }
    });
    $(".magnify").mouseup(function(e) {
        if(e.which === 1) {
            lbDown = false;
        }
    });

    $(".magnify").mousemove(function(e) {
        if(lbDown) {
            //your code here
        }
    });
});
```

We use our own variable to keep track of the left mouse button (`lbDown`). Set it to `true` on mousedown and to `false` on mouseup, then react to this in the `mousemove()`-function.

**EDIT**
Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fMz89/1/) of it.
Of course, you'll want to add some code to hide the magnifying glass once the user stopped dragging it around.

By request, here's the explanation of the logic behind it:
As JS has no native way of checking a mouse-buttons state, we need to implement this feature ourselves.
A mouse-button has two states: it's either `up` or `down`, thus we have to introduce a boolean variable to keep track of the mouse-buttons state (`lbDown` for *left button down* in my code).
Now all we have to do is set this variable according to the state. Luckily, JS provides event-handlers: `mousedown` gets fired once the mouse button is down (clicked) and `mouseup` gets fired once the user releases the clicked button. So we set our boolean variable to `true` in `mousedown` and to `false` in `mouseup`.
We may now check anywhere in the code with a simple `if(lbDown)` if one of the mouse buttons is currently, by the time of the check, down.

The downside is, this would - by now - be true for every mouse-button! We haven't implemented anything yet to distinguish the buttons.
Every event in JS has the property `which`, which lets you determine which key or button was pressed to trigger the (keyboard-/mouse-)event.
Now, when reading the [jQuery API on `which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) we read, that in case of a mouse event, `which` will be `1` for the left mouse button, so we add another if to `mousedown` and `mouseup`, so `lbDown` will only be set, when the left button is clicked.

Comment: @Onaseriousnote can you please fiddle your code or an example?

Comment: i can give you a link

http://www.arrowlife.com/

this is what i have done so far..on mousemove..but now it needs to be on mousedrag

Comment: @Onaseriousnote Works perfectly well for me... see the fiddle in the answer!

Comment: two things..can i know what is the logic behind it...and dint understand the e.which part--e.ehich===1??

Comment: now...the magnifyier does not get initialized..in my case..it appears on the first drag..how can i make it appear on dom ready it self?

http://www.arrowlife.com/index-v2

Comment: The link you provided works like a charme for me (using Chrome). The magnifying glass appears when i begin to click&hold the left mouse button.

Comment: no....you have to wait till the page loads down completely..without clicking...the magnifier should appear...which is not the case now...i hope i am clear

Comment: I would set initial styles (like `display: block; left: 544.5px; top: 78px; background-position: -854px -140px;`, for example) on your `large`-class... as this is the only difference i could spot when comparing the fresh loaded page to an instance where the magnifier is visible.