# I built a magnifying glass in JavaScript but when i click on magnifier handle then my mouse cursor move to center of magnifier circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
$(".menu-left-preview-box-preview").bind('click', function (e) {
    window.location = "page" + ($(this).index() + 1) + ".html";
});

var native_width = 0;
var native_height = 0;
var magnifyIsMouseDown = false;
$(".magnify").parent().mousedown(function (e) {
    magnifyIsMouseDown = true;
});
$(".magnify").mousemove(function (e) {
    if (magnifyIsMouseDown) {
        if (!native_width && !native_height) {
            var image_object = new Image();
            image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");
            native_width = image_object.width;
            native_height = image_object.height;

        } else {
            var magnify_offset = $(this).offset();
            var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
            var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;

            if (mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0) {
                $(".large").fadeIn(100);

            } else {
                $(".large").fadeOut(100);
            }
            if ($(".large").is(":visible")) {
                var rx = Math.round(mx / $(".small").width() * native_width - $(".large").width() / 2) * -1;
                var ry = Math.round(my / $(".small").height() * native_height - $(".large").height() / 2) * -1;
                var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";

                var px = mx - $(".large").width() / 2;
                var py = my - $(".large").height() / 2;
                $(".large").css({ left: px, top: py, backgroundPosition: bgp });
            }
        }
     }
});

$(".magnify").parent().mouseup(function (e) {
    magnifyIsMouseDown = false;
    $(".large").fadeOut(100);
});
$(".magnify").parent().mouseleave(function (e) {
    $(".large").fadeOut(100);
});
```

problem is i click on magnifier handle then my mouse cursor move to center of magnifier circle but i don't want like this. i want it's draggable on handle and circle both means i want to drag magnifier with all x y position of handle and circle

working Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/mohsin80/4ww8efx5/2/

Comment: make your adjustments to these two lines that you wrote  - `var px = mx - $(".large").width() / 2;
                var py = my - $(".large").height() / 2;` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703617/replace-mousemove-by-mousedrag

Comment: not work plz do something

Comment: what did you change? what doesn't work? did you ask the original author of "your" code what they would do?