# How to spin a div?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I would like to have a circular div on my webpage and to be able to spin it as if it were like a wheel of fortune using the mouse. I have tried to use jQuery drag, but I couldn't figure out a way to rotate the div.

Is there a way to rotate div elements using the mouse? Also what would be cool is if it were possible to add momentum?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotating a Div Element in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382591/rotating-a-div-element-in-jquery)

Comment: You should check this jQuery plugin that can rotate elements: https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/ It has good cross-browser support. You could do it with CSS3, but it wouldnt have good browser support. Once you know how to rotate elements with this plugin, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127118/can-you-detect-dragging-in-jquery . This will give you and idea of what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this without ANY Javascript or jQuery by taking advantage of the magic of CSS3 Transitions and Transforms.

First, you need to set your `div` to have a rotation of zero degrees by setting the `transform` attribute like so:

```
div {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
}
```

Then, you just need the hover-based transition (aka, the spin effect). To do that, you can use the `:hover` pseudo element, like so:

```
div:hover {
    transition: transform 1s ease;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

If you would like the element to have a transition where it spins back in place, simply add the transition attribute to the CSS for `div`, like so:

```
div {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
    transition: transform 1s ease;
}
```

Of course, the timing of `1s` is totally up to you; feel free to use any value you want, even `ms` (for milliseconds).

Here's some more information on CSS3 Transitions and Transforms:

- Transitions: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp
- 2D Transforms: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

And here's an example of this kind of rotation in action: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition2.

As for compatibility, it is supported by about 76% of the average browser market: http://caniuse.com/#search=transitions

Note that some browsers don't support the `transition` property as is; some require you to use a vendor prefix for support. For example, Chrome and Safari have the prefix `-webkit-`, so you would put `-webkit-transition: transform 1s ease;` to make it work in those browsers. I have listed the vendor prefixes below:

- Chrome/Safari: `-webkit-`
- Opera: `-o-`
- Firefox: `-moz-`
- Internet Explorer: `-ms-`

Comment: yeah i know it was suppose to be a thumbs up.