# Left click causing interrupt into mousemove handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I notice in the jsfiddle here -http://jsfiddle.net/6NLsm/1/ - that clicking in the beige box causes an entry into the mousemove handler.  How is a click considered to be a mousemove?

Thanks

```
$(function() {
    $('body').mousemove(function(e){
        console.log("mousemove hander: x="+e.clientX+",y="+e.clientY);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a bug related to `Chrome` <strike>(mmmh or `JQuery`)</strike>, try this in `IE10` and no `mousemove` event are triggered on `mouseclick`

```
$(function() {
    $('body').mousemove(function(e){
        //console.log("mousemove hander: x="+e.clientX+",y="+e.clientY);

        console.log(e.type);
    });
});
```

without `Jquery`

```
var p = document.getElementById('box');
p.onmousemove = function () {
    //debugger;
    console.log(arguments[0].type);
};
```

Comment: @Steve what do you think about this?

Comment: Yes, this looks like a Chrome bug. A left click gets sent to the Chrome mouseover handler with e.type = mousemove. The mousemove handler in IE and Firefox doesn't  see a left click event.

Answer (score 0):

I see entries when I move the mouse; however, not when I click. I would guess that when you click you are causing a mouse movement that, while barely perceptible to you is perceptible to the computer which is accurate to detect movement on the pixel level. As @Amit Joki points out in his response you can programmatically ignore clicks in the event that you do make a slight movement while clicking.

Comment: What I want to know in the handler is whether or not a move occurred. Did the user just click something, or did they click and drag?

Comment: @Steve Check out this SO, I think it will get you what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127118/can-you-detect-dragging-in-jquery