# jQuery mousedown() function is not working to trigger on drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, drag, mousedown

I am trying to trigger on drag event using jQuery.

Please find the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/sgsvenkatesh/hepbob75/5/

I used this to trigger on drag event but it is not working.

```
$(document).bind("mousedown", function () { ... });
```

This is acting like a on click event rather than a on drag event.
The same code is working absolutely fine when I use `mousemove` instead of `mousedown` like

```
$(document).bind("mousemove", function () { ... });
```

Is there a way to work on drag event? Or is there any other function which trigger on drag event?

Please let me know if any further information is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to remember where the mouse was clicked and check mouseup to determine if it's a drag. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4139860/1620112.