# JQuery : How to disable mouse move vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating elements selector with mouse click event. ***[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4y8yaqkt/1/)*** link. You can click on one cell and drag as you want *(green color will show)*.
My question is how to disable mouse is moving vertically while click and drag ? Users should be only draggable horizontally. Below is my efforded codes.

**HTML**

```
<div id="grid">
                <div class="gridHeader">
                    <span><label>#</label></span>
                        <span><label>01</label></span>
                        <span><label>02</label></span>
                        <span><label>03</label></span>
                        <span><label>04</label></span>
                        <span><label>05</label></span>
                        <span><label>06</label></span>
                        <span><label>07</label></span>
                        <span><label>08</label></span>
                        <span><label>09</label></span>
                        <span><label>10</label></span>
                </div>
                    <div class="gridRow">
                        <span><label>Room #01</label></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gridRow">
                        <span><label>Room #02</label></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gridRow">
                        <span><label>Room #03</label></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gridRow">
                        <span><label>Room #04</label></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gridRow">
                        <span><label>Room #05</label></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gridRow">
                        <span><label>Room #06</label></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                            <span class="item"></span>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#grid {

}
.gridHeader {
}
#grid .gridHeader > span {
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -3px;
    background-color: silver;
}
#grid .gridHeader > span:FIRST-CHILD {
    width:75px;
}
.gridRow {
}
#grid .gridRow > span {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:16px;
    height:20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -3px;
}
#grid .gridRow > span:FIRST-CHILD {
    width:75px;
    background-color: silver;
}
```

**Scripts**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#grid .item').mousedown(function(){
        $(this).attr("style", "background-color:green");
        $('#grid .item').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).attr("style", "background-color:green");
        });
    });
    $('#grid .item').mouseup(function(){
        $('#grid .item').unbind('mouseenter');
    });
});
```

Comment: FYI, you can't restrict the actual motion of the mouse.  If the user wants to go up and out of your window, they can.  You can restrict what happens when the mouse is moved left/right and ignore the vertical motion.  You will have to implement your hit detection differently so you only respond to items in the row where the drag started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to block the **vertical mousemove**. You just need to catch the proper element and its siblings and also attaching event each to class where the items are placed as below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/4y8yaqkt/3/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.gridRow .item').mousedown(function(){
            $(this).attr("style", "background-color:green");
            $(this).siblings().mouseenter(function(){ 
            //^^^^style only its siblings where mouse has been clicked
                $(this).attr("style", "background-color:green");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh! You gave me a good point. Thank you sir. `$(this).siblings()` is very useful. But I need to unbind event when mouse was released and columns(Room xxx) shouldn't be applied (I think I can handle this). Thanks.

Comment: @Cataclysm.. Anytime!! Happy Coding!! Let know if you face any issue!! For your reference **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4139860/2065039)** might help you!!