# Prevent onClick event when selecting text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I've got this problem where I need to show and hide divs when clicking on a table cell. However, I also want people to be able to select text and copy it within the cell without hiding the information.

Totally open to changing the design if necessary. :)

Here's a fiddle which demonstrates the issue

http://jsfiddle.net/k61u66ek/1/

Here's the HTML code in the fiddle:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Information
        </td>
        <td onClick="toggleInfo()">
            <div id="information" style="display:none">
                More information that I want to select without hiding
            </div>
            <div id="clicktoshow">
                Click to show info
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
function toggleInfo() {
    $("#clicktoshow").toggle();
    $("#information").toggle();    
}
```

Any suggestion/advise is much appreciated!

/Patrik

Comment: Easy solution will be use double click instead of single click. check http://jsfiddle.net/k61u66ek/2/

Answer (score 71, accepted):

One option is to check the `type` of the `Selection` object returned by `window.getSelection`:

```
function toggleInfo() {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    if(selection.type != "Range") {
        $("#clicktoshow").toggle();
        $("#information").toggle();
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k61u66ek/4/

**Update**

If the browser you're targeting doesn't expose a `type` property on the `Selection` object then you can test against the length of the selected value instead:

```
function toggleInfo() {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    if(selection.toString().length === 0) {
        $("#clicktoshow").toggle();
        $("#information").toggle();
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k61u66ek/9/

which can in turn be reduced down to a bool check on `toString`:

`if(!selection.toString()) {`

http://jsfiddle.net/k61u66ek/10/

Comment: Thanks @t00thy, I've updated my answer to include a solution when `type` isn't available.

Comment: Or there is my solution, with catching the time on mouseclick [http://jsfiddle.net/k61u66ek/15/](http://jsfiddle.net/k61u66ek/15/) I set 200 milliseconds as difference between click and copy situation. Maybe it will help.

Comment: it seems toString() is a better option than type=="Range", at least on IE11 & Firefox

Comment: The `toString()` method does not work for example when only images are selected. The `type` approach seems to have good browser support nowadays.

Answer (score 13):

**Code snippet** - cancels click event when text highlighted/selected:

```
document.getElementById('information').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const cellText = document.getSelection();
  if (cellText.type === 'Range') e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/5472ja38/

**Explanation**

`document.getSelection().type` checks on the document object level if any of the text has been highlighted. If so, the *type* property is equal to 'Range' stop the event propagation which will cancel the click toggle button change.

Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection)

> A DOMString describing the type of the current selection. Possible
> values are:
>
> None: No selection has currently been made.
>
> Caret: The selection is
> collapsed (i.e. the caret is placed on some text, but no range has
> been selected).
>
> Range: A range has been selected.

Answer (score 12):

You could check if there is a selection made in the click event handler:

```
window.getSelection().toString();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mouseup`, `mousedown` and `mousemove` events to achieve this:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/k61u66ek/6/)**

```
var isDragging = false;
$("#clickshow")
.mousedown(function() {
    isDragging = false;
})
.mousemove(function() {
    isDragging = true;
 })
.mouseup(function() {
    var wasDragging = isDragging;
    isDragging = false;
    if (!wasDragging) {
        $("#information").toggle();
        $("#clicktoshow").toggle();
    }
});
```

**[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4139860/2065039)**

Answer (score 3):

Another way to go is to use the isCollapsed property of the selection. As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection), it returns true if the start and end of a selection are the same (which is true of a click):

```js
document.getElementById('information').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!window.getSelection().isCollapsed) {
        return;
    }

    // do something here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the 'information' div is toggled :

```
function toggleInfo() {
    if(document.getElementById('information').style.display == 'none'){
         $("#clicktoshow").toggle();
         $("#information").toggle();
   } else { 
       // do nothing
   }
}
```

**Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k61u66ek/8/)**