# Drag and Drop events

Tags: javascript

I have placed an image on canvas, now  I want to be able to drag and drop it anywhere on the canvas. How do I go about it?.

```js
var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.src = "bulb.jpg";

 imageObj.onload = function() {
      canvasContext.drawImage(imageObj, 200,80);        
      };
```

Comment: Did you consider using a plugin ? https://jqueryui.com/draggable/ is pretty useful.

Comment: The plugin  worked great, I have another question is there a way I can use an if statement such that if the image is moved from its original position then something happens.

Comment: @ Demeter Dimitri the plugin worked great though I have another question, is there a way I can use an  if statement such that if image is dragged from its original position then something happens.

Comment: This post can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127118/can-you-detect-dragging-in-jquery