# JavaScript function only for one div, and not whole document

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a [Box2D](https://box2d.org/) composition, I need this code to avoid unintentional clicks:

```js
(() => {
  let lock = 0;
  const prevent = e => {
    if (lock !== 2)
      return;
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  };
  const unlock = e => {
    prevent(e);
    setTimeout(() => lock = 0);
  };
  addEventListener('click', prevent, true);
  addEventListener('pointerdown', e => lock = 1, true);
  addEventListener('pointermove', e => lock && (lock = 2), true);
  addEventListener('pointerup', unlock, true);
  addEventListener('pointercancel', unlock, true);
})();
```

```css
#physics {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="physics"></div>
```

Currently, it works for the whole document. But I would like to have it for the `<div id="physics"></div>` only.

How is it possible to code that?

Would be very thankful for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the div first and then add the handler to that div:

```
let div = document.getElementById('physics');
div.addEventListener('click', prevent, true);
div.addEventListener('pointerdown', e => lock = 1, true);
div.addEventListener('pointermove', e => lock && (lock = 2), true);
div.addEventListener('pointerup', unlock, true);
div.addEventListener('pointercancel', unlock, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
document.getElementById('physics').addEventListener('click', ...);
```